# Passing Object to Create Action in a Form Using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to swap out:

```
   <%= button_tag "Create" , :class => "round" %>
```

for

```
  <%= link_to trips_path(@trip),  :class => "round", :method => :post do %>
    <div id="createtrip_button_newtrip">
      Create
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

in the form

```
<%= form_for @trip, :html =>{ :multipart => true} do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name  %>
  </div>
  <div id="description_container_newtrip">
    <%= f.label :description %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_date, "Start Date:" %><br/>
    <%= f.date_select :start_date, :order => [:month, :day, :year]   %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date, "End Date:" %><br/>
    <%= f.date_select :end_date, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :traveldeal_id %>
  </div>

  <%= #button_tag "Create", :class => "round" %>


  <%= link_to trips_path(@trip),  :class => "round", :method => :post do %>
    <div id="createtrip_button_newtrip">
      Create
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

The link_to calls the correct action in the correct controller, but my form isn't saving. Here is the method:

```
  def create
    @trip = Trip.new(params[:trip])
    if @trip.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end
```

I keep getting redirected to the login_path. I think my problem is that I'm not sending the parameters of @trip over to the controller.

Any tips?

Edit:

Here is the params hash from my development log:

`Started POST "/trips" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-07 15:23:37 -0700 Processing by TripsController#create as HTML Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"+D2icFw2pz6qwYVaeXoWg5MOJg+Sks5/ckN0lVn1r4o="} [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m [1mbegin transaction[0m [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m rollback transaction Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)`

Comment: Please post the params hash. Look in your console and get the params hash from the log of this post.

Comment: @BenMiller Added the params hash per your request.

Comment: As tsherif suspected, the link is not passing the form values.  Try switching to a submit button and see if it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `link_to` doesn't affect the form. You can fix this with a bit of javascript:

```
$(".submit_link").click(function(){
  var link = $(this);
  var form = link.closest("form");
  form.submit();
  return false;
});
```

And then add the class `submit_link` to your link.

If you don't want javascript, use a `submit_tag`, and style it with CSS. For some tips on going that route, see here: http://cssbutton.com/forms/

Comment: Is there an alternative solution where I don't have to use javascript?

Comment: change the link_to to a submit button

Comment: Not really, because `link_to` (`a` elements) don't submit forms. The only other alternative, I think, is to use a `submit_tag`, and then style it with CSS to look the way you want it to.

Comment: No problem. Added some info to my answer about styling submit buttons. Hope that helps.